# ¿Como agregar una imagen a un paciente cuando lo vas a editar en PHP?

Tags: php, html, sql, condiciones

Muy buenos dias para todos, mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un proyecto donde se piden turnos para un paciente, cada paciente tiene su nombre, apellido, la hora, el doctor(que lo va a atender), el local y la foto de la parsona.

Ahora bien, tengo una parte en el proyecto donde necesito editar el paciente creado, en la parte que el paciente se crea necesito que se pueda agregar la foto de la persona pero de despues que se hizo el tratamiento, en esa parte me da el error que no enceuntro, ayudenme plz.

Les dejo por aca el codigo del PHP:

```
if(!isset($_POST['Editar'])){
    header('Location: pacientes.php');
}else{
    include('model/conexion.php');
    $cel=$_POST['Cedula'];
    $nom=$_POST['Nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['Apellido'];
    $tel=$_POST['Telefono'];
    $dir=$_POST['Direccion'];
    $email=$_POST['Email'];
    $id = $_POST['id2'];
    
        $tamaño_img2 = $_FILES['foto_despues']['size'];        
        $tipo_img2 = $_FILES['foto_despues']['type'];

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_FILES)) {
            $rdrd = @getimagesize($_FILES['foto_despues']['tmp_name']);
            if ($rdrd !== false) {
                $carpeta_destino2 = 'img/';
                $archivo_subir2 = $carpeta_destino2 . $_FILES['foto_despues']['name'];
                $pejfoe = $_FILES['foto_despues']['name'];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto_despues']['tmp_name'],$archivo_subir2);
    
            }
        }

    
    $consulta = $con -> prepare("UPDATE pacientes SET CEDULA_PACIENTE=?, 
     NOMBRE_PACIENTE=?, APELLIDO_PACIENTE=?, TELEFONO_PACIENTE=?, DIRECCION_PACIENTE=?, 
     EMAIL_PACIENTE=? WHERE ID_PACIENTE=?;");
    $result = $consulta->execute([$cel,$nom,$apellido,$tel,$dir,$email,$id]);
    $consulta2 = $con ->prepare("INSERT INTO pacientes(FOTO_DESPUES_PACIENTE) VALUE ('$archivo_subir2');");
    $return = $consulta2->execute();
if($result == true){
    header('Location: pacientes.php');
}else{
    echo "error de actualizacion";
}    }
```

En esta parte hago la edicion, y pido en $tamaño_img2 el nombre por $_files que es foto_despues

Ahora les paso el html que es donde le pongo el nombre:

```
                 <label for="Foto">
                    Foto Despues:
                    <input type="file" size="20" name="foto_despues">
                </label>
```

El tema es que como el paciente ya fue creado osea ya tiene su nombre, apellido,etc, necesito que al editar se agrege la foto de despues (no la de antes).
Si es necesario alguna otra cosa me avisan por los comentarios que estoy por aqui.

Formulario html:

```
       <form action="editar_paciente_proceso.php" 
                 method="POST" autocomplete="false">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Cedula">Cedula
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Cedula" id="cedula" placeholder="Escribe tu Cedula" required value="<?php echo $paciente->CEDULA_PACIENTE ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Nombre">Nombre
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Escribe tu Nombre" required value="<?php echo $paciente->NOMBRE_PACIENTE ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Apellido">Apellido
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Apellido" id="apellido" placeholder="Escribe tu Apellido" required value="<?php echo $paciente->APELLIDO_PACIENTE ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Telefono">Telefono/Celular
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Escribe tu Telefono" required value="<?php echo $paciente->TELEFONO_PACIENTE ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Direccion">Direccion
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Escribe tu Direccion" required value="<?php echo $paciente->DIRECCION_PACIENTE ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email">Email
                        <input class="form-control" type="Email" name="Email" id="email" placeholder="Escribe tu Email" required value="<?php echo $paciente->EMAIL_PACIENTE ?>">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <label for="Foto">
                    Foto Despues:
                    <input type="file" size="20" name="foto_despues">
                </label>
                

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id2" value="<?php echo $paciente->ID_PACIENTE ?>">
                    <input class="btn btn-dark btn-md mb-3 mt-3" type="submit" value="Editar Paciente" name="Editar">
                </div>
                <a href="pacientes.php" class="btn btn-md btn-dark mb-3">Regresar</a>
            </form>
```

Imagen del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: Necesitamos ver todo el formulario, pues es probable que alli tengas el error tambien. Por ejemplo, ¿estas usando `enctype="multipart/form-data"` como atributo del form que estás mandando?

Comment: @masterguru hola, no no ese atributo, para que sirve?

Comment: @orici el error es que no me muestra la la foto de despues y no se cual es el error que da

Comment: Ese atributo sirve para que el formulario envie bien la variable $_FILES, sino está vacia.  Ponlo así: `<form action="editar_paciente_proceso.php" method="POST" autocomplete="false" enctype="multipart/form-data">` y prueba de nuevo a ver si avanzas ahora

Comment: @masterguru hola muy buenos dias, proble lo que me dijiste del form y no avanze

Comment: @masterguru me esta agregando pacientes en la base de datos con todos los campos en 0 y el de la foto esta bien, huuuu porqueeeeeeeeeee, emm sabes que puede estar pasando?, osea lo que quiero que haga es editar el paciente no que me agrege otro

Comment: Te agrega esos registros con 0/null por que haces un INSERT con sólo la foto; ¿Por qué insertar cuando quieres actualizar y ya tienes un UPDATE?.

Comment: eso es verdad @Sal pero estube probando hacerlo con UPDATE y no se como hacerlo, sabes como arreglar eso?

Comment: Sólo agrega la columna FOTO_DESPUES_PACIENTE donde -y como- están las otras.

Comment: Sisisi ya intente pero no funciona, me tira un error que no consoco, algo asi dices?      $consulta = $con -> prepare("UPDATE pacientes SET CEDULA_PACIENTE=?, NOMBRE_PACIENTE=?, APELLIDO_PACIENTE=?, TELEFONO_PACIENTE=?, DIRECCION_PACIENTE=?, EMAIL_PACIENTE=?, FOTO_DESPUES_PACIENTE=$archivo_subir2 WHERE ID_PACIENTE=?;");
        $result = $consulta->execute([$cel,$nom,$apellido,$tel,$dir,$email,$id]);

Comment: Observa que las variables `$` van en el `execute`, en el `prepare` va un marcador de posición `?`. Las variables van en el mismo orden que sus respectivos marcadores de posición.

Comment: dou, era eso ahahahahahahhaa

Comment: ahi funciono ._.

Comment: puedes publicar la respuesta junto con el enctype="multipart/form-data" de @masterguru que tambien esta bien?